# Using Python to search an item in a website

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, web, search

I wrote this script with some online help just to start developing my coding skills. The script supposed to return the data for searching an item in a particular website.  But it never brings a readable data back! I tried this code on other websites too but they are all give me the same results! Does anyone know what the problem is and where I am going wrong?

```
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 import requests
 import lxml
 import json

headers = {
'User-agent':
"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win6a4; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"}

name = input("What to search?")
url = "https://www.target.com/s?searchTerm=" + name
html = requests.get(url, headers=headers).text

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

print(url)
print(soup)
```

[The Results I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPaXn.png)

Comment: you may have the most common problem: page may use `JavaScript` to add/update elements but `BeautifulSoup`/`lxml`, `requests`/`urllib` can't run `JS`. You may need [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)  to control real web browser which can run `JS`. OR use (manually) `DevTools` in `Firefox`/`Chrome` (tab `Network`) to see if `JavaScript` reads data from some URL. And try to  use this URL with `requests`. `JS` usually gets `JSON` which can be easy converted to Python dictionary (without `BS`). You can also check if page has (free) `API` for programmers.

Comment: you going wrong because you expect you get readable data. This code gives you only HTML from server and now you have to use `beautifulsoup` to search expected data in this HTML. It will NOT do it automatically for you.

Comment: if portal has some API then you may expect readable data as JSON (using API) but normally you have to write many lines of code to extract data from HTML.